# Change color of scipy plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, colors, scipy

I am trying to change the plot color using one of the many [matplotlib's named color](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/named_colors.html) but can't do it for a plot done using one of the functions in scipy. Specifically the [`signal.welch`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.welch.html) function. Any help is appreciated.

```py
import librosa.display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy import signal

filename = "sample.wav"

y, sr = librosa.load(filename)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, sharex=True)

f, Pxx_den = signal.welch(y, sr, nperseg=1024)
ax[0].semilogy(f, Pxx_den)
ax[0].set_xlabel('Hz')
ax[0].set_ylabel('Power')
ax[0].set_title('Power Spectral Density')
```

I have tried passing `color='coral'` into `signal.welch` but that does not change the color.
`ax[0].plot(color='coral')` after `set_title` also does not work. The plot remains blue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add the `color='coral'` to the `ax[0].semilogy(f, Pxx_den)` like so `ax[0].semilogy(f, Pxx_den, color='coral')`.

This changes the plot color.